# MYSQL LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, null, load-data-infile

I use LOAD DATA INFILE in mysql. In my input file I have "x" character but I have to save it to database as NULL. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
load data infile... 
into table ...
fields terminated by...
lines terminated by ...
(
 my_field...
)
set 
my_field = if(my_field = 'x', null, my_field);
```

Comment: It is pretty useful but it first assigns x to date then changes to null. Which is violates the rule that "date can not be 'x'"

Comment: huh ?? as it's loading it checks the value of my_field. if it's 'x' it writes a null otherwise it writes the original value.

Comment: oh it's a date field - would have been helpful if you'd mentioned that earlier !

Answer (score 1):

```
load data infile... 
into table ...
fields terminated by...
lines terminated by ...
(
 @var...
)
set 
my_field = if(@var = 'x', null, @var);
```

Thanks to pekka